# Include Twig in Cpanle host

Tags: php, twig, hosting, cpanel, web-hosting

I want to use twig in my php project running in my host. The code works properly in my localhost server but it does not work in my host. Should I set any configuration in my host?
Here is my index.php:

```
<?php
try{
echo "Under Construction";
require_once "/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php";
echo "require_once is OK";
Twig_Autoloader::register();
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('tmpl');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

echo $twig->render('index.twig', array('name' => 'Ali'));
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Error: " . $e.getMessage();
}
```

It shows nothing (even any error message!) and just I see "Under Construction" when I go to rkeshmir.ir

Answer (score 0):

I found my fault!
It should be    "./lib/Twig/Autoloader.php"    instead of    "/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php"    . A dot is forgotten.